# Spring 3.0: "The prefix" X "for attribute" Y "associated with an element type" Z "is not bound"

Tags: java, xml, spring, xsd

My app was working fine until this morning but I started getting the errors below after I renamed my Netbeans 6.9 project this morning.

I'm getting the following error when building my Spring 3.0.4 app:

```
The prefix "p" for attribute "p:driverClassName" associated with an element type "beans:bean" is not bound
```

applicationContext.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xmlns:security="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
  xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
       xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
       xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"

       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-3.0.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.0.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.0.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/security http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-3.0.3.xsd">


    <bean id="myEmf" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalEntityManagerFactoryBean">
        <property name="persistenceUnitName" value="TT-SpringMVCPU"/>
    </bean>

    <bean id="configurationLoader"
        class="org.springmodules.validation.bean.conf.loader.annotation.AnnotationBeanValidationConfigurationLoader"/>

    <bean id="validator"
        class="org.springmodules.validation.bean.BeanValidator"
        p:configurationLoader-ref="configurationLoader"
        p:errorCodeConverter-ref="errorCodeConverter"/>

    <bean id="errorCodeConverter"
        class="org.springmodules.validation.bean.converter.KeepAsIsErrorCodeConverter"/>
  <bean id="messageSource"
        class="org.springframework.context.support.ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource"
        p:basename="WEB-INF/errors"/>

    <bean id="TT-SQLServer"
          class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource"
          p:driverClassName="net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Driver"
          p:url="jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://localhost:1234/TTToys"
          p:username="sa"
          p:password="Password1" />
    </beans>
```

applicationContext-security:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<beans:beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
    xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
                        http://www.springframework.org/schema/security http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-3.0.xsd">


    <http auto-config='true'>
         <intercept-url pattern="/login" access="IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY"/>
         <intercept-url pattern="/secure/**" access="ROLE_USER" />
        <form-login login-page='/login' />
    </http>


    <authentication-manager>
        <authentication-provider user-service-ref='myUserDetailsService'/>
    </authentication-manager>

    <beans:bean id="myUserDetailsService"
      class="org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.jdbc.JdbcDaoImpl">
        <beans:property name="dataSource" ref="TT-SQLServer"/>
    </beans:bean>
</beans:beans>
```

The above error is causing this error:

```
Nov 24, 2010 10:52:54 AM org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader initWebApplicationContext
SEVERE: Context initialization failed
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'myEmf' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is javax.persistence.PersistenceException: No Persistence provider for EntityManager named TT-SpringMVCPU
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1420)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:519)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:456)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:291)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:288)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:190)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:563)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:895)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:425)
        at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.createWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:276)
        at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:197)
        at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:47)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4135)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:4630)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:791)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:771)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:546)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDescriptor(HostConfig.java:637)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployApps(HostConfig.java:521)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.check(HostConfig.java:1359)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.modeler.BaseModelMBean.invoke(BaseModelMBean.java:297)
        at com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:836)
        at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.JmxMBeanServer.invoke(JmxMBeanServer.java:761)
        at org.apache.catalina.manager.ManagerServlet.check(ManagerServlet.java:1500)
        at org.apache.catalina.manager.ManagerServlet.deploy(ManagerServlet.java:849)
        at org.apache.catalina.manager.ManagerServlet.doGet(ManagerServlet.java:351)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:617)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:290)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:233)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:191)
        at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:563)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:127)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:298)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:857)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:588)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:489)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:619)
Caused by: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: No Persistence provider for EntityManager named TT-SpringMVCPU
        at javax.persistence.Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(Unknown Source)
        at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalEntityManagerFactoryBean.createNativeEntityManagerFactory(LocalEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:92)
        at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:308)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1477)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1417)
        ... 45 more
```

persistence.xml

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <persistence version="2.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd">
      <persistence-unit name="TT-SpringMVCPU" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
        <provider>org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.PersistenceProvider</provider>
        <class>com.sajee.TT.db.Categories</class>

        <exclude-unlisted-classes>false</exclude-unlisted-classes>
        <properties>
          <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.url" value="jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://localhost:1234/TailSpinToys"/>
          <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.password" value="Password1"/>
          <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.driver" value="net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Driver"/>
          <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.user" value="sa"/>
        </properties>
      </persistence-unit>
    </persistence>
```

See anything wrong here?

Comment: Everything looks fine. the namespace p is declared correctly and "driverClassName" is valid setter. Is there any other error message?

Comment: @scheffield: updated the question w/ a related error.  This started when I renamed my Netbeans 6.9 project this morning.

Comment: Did you ever checked if the problem is the p namespace: simply by using the old school <property name="" value=""/> syntacy for the DriverManagerDataSource instead of p: .  -- It is because i do not belive that the p namespace is the cause of your problem.

Comment: I don't think we can find something wrong in the code, since it clearly looks like some Netbeans project misconfiguration. "No persistence provider" can be cause by absense of `/META-INF/persistence.xml` in the classpath, as well as by absense of persistence provider implementation. Problem with `p`-namespace looks like a result of some unnecessary XML validation.

Comment: I'm not sure what happened but probably a Netbeans hiccup since after restarting and doing a clean build a few times fixed the problem.  Thank you all for the help.

Answer (score 8):

You need to add namespaces to your beans declaration.

> xmlns:c="http://www.springframework.org/schema/c"
>      xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"

See the spring documentation reference.

http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.2.x/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html#beans-p-namespace

Answer (score 4):

I don't have any experience with Netbeans, but I guess the problem might be related to XML schema for the `p` namespace.

It's a wild guess, but let me take it. Maybe you had configured Netbeans to add a custom XSD to its catalog and pointed to the XSD file within your project. After you renamed the project, the path to `p` namespace XML schema is invalid.

I don't even know if such XML catalog configuration is possible in Netbeans, I am more into Eclipse. But I would check that in your place.

Answer (score 3):

I know i am late but i got same error and may be this is usefull to others.. i put the

```
p:something
```

into

```
<property name="something" value="anything_you_want_to_set"/>
```

So, instead of

```
p:driverClassName="net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Driver"
```

try this :

```
<bean>
    <property name="driverClassName" value="net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Driver" />
    <!-- and your others property -->
</bean>
```