# Error in configuring EhCache and Spring

Tags: spring, ehcache

**My Context file looks like this**

```
<bean id="cacheManager" class="org.springframework.cache.ehcache.EhCacheCacheManager" p:cacheManager-ref="ehcache"/>
<bean id="ehcache" class="org.springframework.cache.ehcache.EhCacheManagerFactoryBean" p:configLocation="classpath:spring/cache/ehcache.xml" p:shared="true"/>
```

**My EhCache.xml looks like this:**

```
<defaultCache eternal="false" maxElementsInMemory="1000"
    overflowToDisk="false" diskPersistent="false" timeToIdleSeconds="0"
    timeToLiveSeconds="600" memoryStoreEvictionPolicy="LRU"/>

<cache name="bdmCache" eternal="false"
    maxElementsInMemory="100" overflowToDisk="false" diskPersistent="false"
    timeToIdleSeconds="0" timeToLiveSeconds="300"
    memoryStoreEvictionPolicy="LRU" />
```

**I get below copied exception when i start my tomcat**

28/Jul/2014 09:32:05 977 ERROR    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet [localhost-startStop-1] - Context initialization failed (org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initServletBean(FrameworkServlet.java:467))
org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionStoreException: Line 38 in XML document from class path resource [spring/web/spring-web.xml] is invalid; nested exception is org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 38; columnNumber: 118; The prefix "p" for attribute "p:cacheManager-ref" associated with an element type "bean" is not bound.
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.doLoadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:396)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:334)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:302)

**Please tell me what i am missing here.**

Answer (score 0):

There is some problem with your namespaces configuration as the exception suggests: The prefix "p" for attribute "p:cacheManager-ref" associated with an element type "bean" is not bound.

Share your namespace configuration here. As per the current information present nothing more can be added. More on namespace and configurations [here](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.0.x/reference/xsd-config.html).
Related [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4268536/spring-3-0-the-prefix-x-for-attribute-y-associated-with-an-element-type-z).